# use inline-block or table-cell for css grid

Tags: css, web-applications, grid, frontend

I'm looking into creating a set of css grid classes for webkit only browsers. Should be simillar to blueprit/bootstrap/compass, however I'd rather not use those because they rely on float positioning.

I'd like something like this:

```
span-1 {width:10%;display:inline-block}
span-2 {width:20%;display:inline-block}
```

and so on.  Would there be any benefit to using display:table-cell vs inline-block for this?  Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `display: table` is really the solution you are probably looking for (because of your target browsers).  It was added to browsers so people could get a grid layout without needing to use a table.  You don't even need percentages (the number of columns you add will dictate the width of the children elements).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/egGSX/)

The only real caveat comes in when you are doing mobile browsers and want a dynamic layout shift (media tag) to go from a horizontal list to a vertical list.  I guess it is not too big of a deal to add you own media tags (and add a class to the wrapper)...

You probably could get `display: inline-block` working but make sure you use `box-sizing: border-box` because when you are working with percentages, even a single px off and things start wrapping..